# Issue with drag and drop

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I use the following code to drag and drop a file into a c# winforms application. The issue I have is that the DragDrop event handler takes a while, and during this time I can't use the window from which I dragged the file. How can this be fixed?

```
private void FormMain_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    // do some long operation
}

private void FormMain_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
else
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

Comment: Just take drag+drop out of the question and run the "long operation" with a button's Click event.  That question has been asked many, many times already.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you give some clearer answer or point me to one of those many, many times the question was asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do the operation that you need in different thread like the following :

```
    BackgroundWorker bgw;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
    }

    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync(s);
        }

    }
```

Also for your issue "cross thread operation", try to use the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Method like this :

```
    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new Action<object>((args) =>
        {
            string[] files = (string[])args;

        }), e.Argument);
    }
```

Its better to check if the dropped items are files using [`GetDataPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idataobject.getdatapresent.aspx) like above.

Comment: Thanks, but: 1. Action () requires an argument.  2. How to assign bgw_DoWork to bgw?

Comment: Still not working. Did you test that? The lambda statement isn't executed.

Comment: I changed it to pass the argument object as it to the bgw and later cast it as string[]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a background thread for this long-running operation, if it is not ui-intensive.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => /* long running operation*/)
```

Comment: I get a "cross thread operation not valid" exception. This is probably due to accessing a richtextbox in this operation. Can this be fixed?