# Accessing WinForms Control from separate thread and class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class named "tables", and a winform "Form1", on the form is a button called "table3". The code in the "tables" class runs in a separate thread and needs access to the button on the main form, this is what I have:

```
Form1.ActiveForm.BeginInvoke(
(Action)(() =>
{
    Form1.ActiveForm.Controls["table3"].Text = "test";
}));
```

I'm getting a null reference exception.. The name of the button is correct. there's some other problem and I'm not sure what it could be :/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110458/winforms-interthread-modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Invoke(new Action<object>((args) =>
{
    Form1.ActiveForm.Controls["table3"].Text = "test";
}));
```

Comment: e.Argument - e does not exist in the current context

Comment: OK, I edited the answer. You can also use it in a backgroundworker as in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373299/issue-with-drag-and-drop

Comment: Using a backround worker would require a whole lot of my code to be modified.. hmm

Comment: OK, as in the edit, just remove the second argument.

Comment: Still doesn't work, but I'll go with the backround worker, thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: You mean you're getting an error? or doesn' update gui. I guess null refernce would mean that "Form1.ActiveForm.Controls["table3"]" may be null. Try a breakpoint there and use watch or pin to source

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a NullReferenceException, then a reference is null. So either `Form1.ActiveForm == null`, or `Form1.ActiveForm.Controls == null`, or `Form1.ActiveForm.Controls["table3"] == null`.

I assume `Form1` is the name of the class and `ActiveForm` is a static property.